# Search function in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I have tried to create a search function with Javascript, but it doesn't work.

```
function contains(text_one, text_two) {
    if (text_one.indexof(text_two) != -1)
        return true;
}

$("#searchText").onkeyup(function(){
    var searchText = $("searchText").val().toLowerCase()
    $("ul li").each(function() {
        if (!contains($(this).text().toLowerCase(), searchText))
            $(this).hide();
        else
            $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please give us your HTML, CSS (if there is any), and JavaScript. Also tell, what are you trying to achieve and what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug all of these issues by yourself using the developer console. If you press <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser you will be able to see all the errors that your JS code is raising and address them.

From the above, I can see that you have several issues in your code:

- You should use `indexOf`, not `indexof`, as JS is case-sensitive
- The `$('searchText')` selector is missing the `id` prefix: `$('#searchText')`
- jQuery has no `onkeyup` method, it's just `keyup`.

Also note that you can improve the logic by using `toggle()` and just returning the result of the `indexOf` comparison in the `contains()` function. Try this:

```
function contains(text_one, text_two) {
    return text_one.toLowerCase().indexOf(text_two.toLowerCase()) != -1;
}

$("#searchText").keyup(function(){
    var searchText = $(this).val();
    $("ul li").each(function() {
        $(this).toggle(contains($(this).text(), searchText));
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pdgucocw/)

Comment: ty ,i solve it,you are so kind~~xd